# search value from one sheet to anther sheet in excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets in Excel. I want to determine whether a value from sheet1 exists in sheet2. The following code doesn't produce any output or error on my file.

```
Sub t()
    For i = 2 To 48
        For j = 2 To 48
            If Worksheets("Operator PC").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("PC Locations").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                MsgBox "Value"
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please give some more information about your file (the data, sheet names etc. - maybe in form of a screenshot)

Comment: as it looks to me: no value in `'Operator PC'!A2:A48` is equal to any value in `'PC Locations'!A2:A48`... keep in mind that this is case sensitive and "PC2435R" is not "PC2435r". Pls Check if `=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Operator PC'!A2:A48,'PC Locations'!A2:A48,0)))` (array formula! confirm with ctrl+shift+enter) returns `TRUE`. If not, then your `Sub` probably works without any errors... (keep in mind that this formula is NOT case sensitive)

Comment: Also suggest testing it with Debug.Print ("i=" & i & " j=" & j) instead of MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub t()
    Dim rFirst As Range
        Set rFirst = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rSecond As Range
        Set rSecond = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In rFirst
        Set rFound = rSecond.Find(rCell, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then MsgBox (rCell.Value)
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

If the sheet is very big, it is better to load the ranges into memory first with a variant instead of a range variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution as Excel (assuming PC version) can use the Windows Jet/ACE SQL Engine to run queries on workbooks including the current file. Here, you avoid the nested `For` loop and if/then logic, and even can extend to match other columns or various `WHERE` conditions.

Below runs an inner join query between both worksheets and outputs results to an existing sheet named *Matches*. Be sure to change *ColA* in strSQL with actual column 1 header. Two connection strings are included for Driver and Provider types.

```
Sub RunSQL() 
   Dim conn As Object, rst As Object 
   Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
   Dim LastRow As Integer

   Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
   Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   ' Specify full workbook path
   ' strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _ 
   '                  & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;" 
   strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _ 
                    & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _ 
                    & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

   ' OPEN DB CONNECTION 
   conn.Open strConnection

   strSQL = " SELECT o.ColA FROM ['Operator PC'$] o" _ 
              & " INNER JOIN ['PC Location'$] p" _ 
              & " ON o.ColA = p.ColA"

   ' OPEN QUERY RECORDSET 
   rst.Open strSQL, conn

   ' COPY DATA TO WORKSHEET 
   LastRow = Worksheets("Matches").Cells(Worksheets("Matches") _ 
             .Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
   Worksheets("Matches").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).CopyFromRecordset rst 

   rst.Close
   conn.Close

End Sub
```